# Why I am getting syntax error:unknown work in tailwind CSS

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, jit

I am getting the following error as shown in the picture.
I have enabled *jit* mode in tailwind CSS and It used to work fine.

This is the error I got recently without making any changes in tailwind config.
If I remove the first 3 lines of `./styles/global.css` that is
`@tailwind base; @tailwind components; @tailwind utilities;`   
It works
If i removed `mode:'jit'` in tailwind config It works.
Both of the above is something I need and can't remove , Is there any solution to It.

Here is the `tailwind.config.js` file for reference.

```
   module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  purge: ['./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  darkMode: false,
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: () => ({
        'sprite-background': "url('/images/icons.png')",
      }),
      boxShadow: {
        fb: '0 -2px 5px rgb(128,128,128)',
        fbpanel: '0 1px 10px grey',
        img: '2px 3px 12px #d3d3d3',
      },
      // compiled the css with the below primary and secondary colors and linked with _app.tsx.
      colors: {
        primary: '#C54582',
        secondary: '#F4DCF4',
        'app-background': '#fff',
        orange: '#ff5a42',
        workItem: '#f5f5dc',
        workItemActive: '#81816d',
        plannedIncome: 'rgba(97,255,42,.43)',
        plannedExpense: 'rgba(255,114,114,.49)',
      },
      fontFamily: {
        sans: [
          'Source Sans Pro',
          'sans-serif',
          'ui-sans-serif',
          'system-ui',
          '-apple-system',
          'BlinkMacSystemFont',
          '"Segoe UI"',
          'Roboto',
          '"Helvetica Neue"',
          'Arial',
          '"Noto Sans"',
          '"Apple Color Emoji"',
          '"Segoe UI Emoji"',
          '"Segoe UI Symbol"',
          '"Noto Color Emoji"',
        ],
        serif: ['ui-serif', 'Georgia', 'Cambria', '"Times New Roman"', 'Times', 'serif'],
        mono: [
          'ui-monospace',
          'SFMono-Regular',
          'Menlo',
          'Monaco',
          'Consolas',
          'Liberation Mono',
          'Courier New',
          'monospace',
        ],
      },
      flex: {
        2: '2',
      },
      gridTemplateColumns: {
        financeHeader: '24rem 1fr',
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

[image]

[image]

// global.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


p{
    @apply ml-1 mt-8;
}

li{
    @apply mt-1;
}

h1{
    @apply text-4xl;
}

h2{
    @apply font-semibold ml-1 mt-8;
}

ul{
    @apply list-disc ml-1 mt-8;
}
```

Comment: Can you share screenshot of your project directory structure?

Comment: @iftikharyk sure, I have added now in the question.

Comment: Can you please show us your full `tailwind.config.js` (it may be related)?

Comment: Please share your global.css file as well. There might be any problem with that.

Comment: Updated It , It used to work with this configuration before.

Comment: @HussamKhatib let me show your `next.config.js` file.

Answer (score 1):

There was nothing wrong with how tailwind CSS was configured.
I am not 100% sure ,but the error went away when I removed the tailwind class using JIT syntax whose value was dynamically updated.
for example

```
<div className=`margin-[${marvalToBeCalcEveryRender}]px` />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (even with the dynamic class code commented out!) After digging through JIT issues on GitHub, I realized it was because tailwind is parsing the file for classes at build time (not run time).

That class wouldn’t work, but something like `margin-[50px]` would because tailwind knows what class to build with that code ahead of runtime.

PS I’m no expert, but that’s how I understood the problem and fixed it.